# Generating maps of several variables

Tags: qgis, print-composer, batch, mapping

I have a map. I have external data that I can join to the map by name of the feature. The data contains several variables, say abc, def, xyz1, xyz2 and xyz3.

I can display a variable by selecting it in the symbology of the map layer. I created a print layout with a legend which works for all variables xyz*.

How can I (batch) generate separate maps (in png) for all variables xyz*?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution yet for batch symbolization but if you have symbolized each variable, here is a script that will loop through the selected layers turning each off printing to a pdf & then turning it off.  I shouldn't be too difficult to change the pdf to a png.

```
def printpdfmulti(layoutname):
    selected_layers = qgis.utils.iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
    projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
    layoutmanager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
    layout = layoutmanager.layoutByName(layoutname) #Layout nameprojectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
    for layer in selected_layers:
        QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(True)
        layout.refresh()
        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
        filename = "".join(i for i in layer.name() if i not in "\/:*?<>|")
        exporter.exportToPdf("C://data//" + filename + ".pdf", QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings() )
        QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)


printpdfmulti("plane_view1")
```

Comment: I am quite new to qgis. I found that I can create and run this script from the processing toolbox. However, the first line already gives the exception: name 'qgis' is not defined. Btw: I don't have multiple layers. I have only 1 map layer and I need to cycle through some of the columns of the data file (which I think one should select via symbology in the map layer). If there is a better way to generate maps and png for the different columns in my data file, I am open to suggestions. Thanks.